# Let $A = (0,1)∪\{2,3\}$. In the usual topology, prove that there is a point in A that is a limit point of A

Tags: general-topology

Let $A = (0,1)∪\{2,3\}.$ In the usual topology, prove that there is a point in A that is a limit point of A

any help please with that , I think 0 and 1 are limit point of A but they are not in A  , my struggle with how can I show there is a point in A that is a limit point of A

?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you write down the definition of a limit point? There are only so many [types of] points in $A$ that you can try...

Comment: I think 0 and 1 are limit point of A but they are not in A

Comment: Your question explicitly states to find "**a point in $A$** that is a limit point of $A$."

Comment: It's strange question.  0 and 1 are limit points but they aren't the only ones.  Any point between 0 and 1 are all limit points too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $S$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. A point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of $S$ if **every** neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of S different from $x$ itself.

Now, consider any point in the interval $(0,1)$, say $1/2$,    obviously any neighborhood of $1/2$ contains at least one point of $(0,1)$ different from $1/2$. Therefore $1/2$ is a limit point.

But $2$ isn't a limit point since there is a neighborhood of it,say $(1,3)$ that doesn't contain any point of A different from $2$.